# Ignition turn off

Tags: engine, ignition, opel

I use Opel Corsa D 1.3cdti. The ignition mostly turns off when I’m descending hill with neutral gear. What could be the problem?

Comment: Isn’t that a diesel engine?  There is no ignition in a diesel engine.

Comment: If I should put it this way, the engine turns off.